# Headset appearing as only input, tried so many things to fix and out of ideas. ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, headset, input, output

I have searched googled for a very long time, I am about ready to start pulling my hair out.

I have headset with built in mic, no matter what USB port I use it only shows as a Mic in Sound Settings or Pavo.

When I user "#  alsamixer" in terminal it shows the all the headset speakers AND the mic, and nothing is muted. trust me nothing is muted anywhere.

I recently switched off the nouveau driver before I ever tried using the headset, because my games didnt work with that driver, counter strike was choppy and required very low graphics to run and war thunder was crashing at boot. I switched to NVIDIA 340 and once my games worked I went to try and play steam with my headset on and now its not working, and now I switched to 331 and it still is not working!

I suppose I could switch to Nouveau again but then I'll be back to not being able to run my games and not needing the headset.

Does anyone have a solution? Are there audio drivers or....idk anything I would need to add or update through terminal to get my headset to be recognized as both an output and an input device?

Comment: What is the problem?  Do you want to use something other than the headset as an input, and if so, what?

Comment: My computer speakers work fine. I want my headphones to work, only the mic will work, and the audio won't play through them.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I needed to play around with the USB port while force reloading alsa with

$ sudo alsa force-reboot

It didn't work at first which led me to searching for other solutions and wasting a bunch of hours of time. Hope this helps people in my predicament in the future

Comment: the command is `sudo alsa force-reload`